# EB Django config commands error

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy my django app on EB for few days but I keep getting an error trying to run a command. So basically, when I try to deploy the app it gives me "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory."
For the full error, this is what I get after running `eb deploy` on my terminal.

```
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
--- Waiting for Application Versions to be pre-processed ---
Finished processing application version app-e8a0-170203_135603 
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                          
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Degraded. 100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 requests/min) to determine application health. Command failed on all instances. Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app-e8a0-170203_135603" (deployment 43). Application update in progress (running for 2 seconds).
ERROR: [Instance: i-05377fd0bcfa86dd6] Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: python: can't open file 'HungryBoat/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. 
command 03_migrate in .ebextensions/03_commands.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-05377fd0bcfa86dd6'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

**error message from logs**:

```
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.082Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_HungryBoat] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.082Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_HungryBoat/Command 01_migrate] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.147Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_HungryBoat/Command 01_migrate] : Activity execution failed, because: python: can't open file '/opt/python/current/app/hungryboat/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2017-02-03T21:05:46.147Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_HungryBoat/Command 01_migrate] : Activity failed.
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.147Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_1_HungryBoat] : Activity failed.
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.147Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Activity failed.
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.413Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Activity failed.
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.413Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-02-03T21:05:46.414Z] INFO  [2980]  - [Application deployment app-019d3-170203_154910@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
```

here's the **config file** I have:

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "hungryboat.settings"
        PYTHONPATH: "./hungryboat"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: "hungryboat/wsgi.py"
        NumProcesses: 3
        NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        "/static/": "www/static/"

commands:

    01_pip_update:
        command: "pip install --upgrade pip"
        leader_only: true
    02_pip_freeze:
        command: "pip freeze > requirements.txt"
    03_migrate:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
        leader_only: true
    04_collect_static:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

I've tried putting project name in front of manage.py but still gives me the same error. I don't know how I can solve this. please save this poor soul. thanks.

EDIT: **project directory tree** looks more or less like this:

```
hungryboat
├── hungryboat/.ebextensions
├── hungryboat/.elasticbeanstalk
├── hungryboat/accounts
├── hungryboat/dump.rdb
├── hungryboat/hungryboat
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/asgi.py
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/__init__.py
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/migrations
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/routing.py
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/settings.py
│   ├── hungryboat/hungryboat/urls.py
│   └── hungryboat/hungryboat/wsgi.py
├── hungryboat/manage.py
├── hungryboat/menu
├── hungryboat/pickplace
├── hungryboat/README.md
├── hungryboat/requirements.txt
├── hungryboat/static
└── hungryboat/venv
```

** EDIT: Fixed above problem but now I'm getting different error **

inside the **settings.py** I have,

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['APP_SECRET_KEY']
```

but I'm getting this **ERROR**

```
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-0c46f0a9e5069d5bf] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

FYI, I have APP_SECRET_KEY inside EB Environment Variables.

Comment: Why do you install pip and create requirements inside instance? What you have to do is create a requirements.txt on your local project folder. When you deploy, EB automatically installs all of the packages in that requirements file. First, You delete your first 2 commands. Maybe you should just start over with documentation. You don't have to do everything you do on your local when you deploy to AWS.

Comment: They still run perfectly fine until it hits migration command though which is where I'm stuck at. :(

Comment: Do you have another config file? or is there any other commant above these commands?

Comment: updated question. That's pretty much waht I have

Comment: Example: 03_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python opt/python/current/app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
     DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "hungryboat.settings"
     PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/hungryboat:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
     WSGIPath: "hungryboat/wsgi.py"
     NumProcesses: 3
     NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
     "/static/": "www/static/"

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collect_static:
    command: "python /opt/python/current/app/hungryboat/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Your pythonpath is wrong, that's why it can't find manage.py file. First change the pythonpath and try again. Also make sure you have a requirements.txt on your local project. You shouldn't create requirements in your instance, you should create on your local and when you deploy, it will install all packages in your requirements with pip.

Comment: @JohnD. Can you also add your requirements.txt and deployment error log again?

Comment: I have added error log to the question but my requirements.txt is really long list but the log shows that all the things on requirements.txt is installed without an error

Comment: I got more questions :) 1. In your config file inside .elastic beanstalk, what is source? Is it git? If it's git, did you commit and push the changes? 2. Run "eb ssh" and go to your project directory to check if manage.py is there? To do that, run  "cd /opt/python/current/app/hungryboat"

Comment: it's in the /opt/python/current/app not /opt/python/current/app/hungryboat :\

Comment: Then something must've changed recently because I took it from my project config. OK then now update it and try again. If it gives error again, update the logs on question and let me know. EDIT : I guess project name should be added to the app directory so it should stay there :/

Comment: Maybe you can just find another tutorial and follow that.

Comment: Now that's working, I'm getting another one. I put the error up there and where it's getting error. Could you help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even though you say you added envvars, it clearly doesn't see it. How did you add to EB Environment Variables? I know 2 ways. First one is to add it to your config file (just below to your  PYTHONPATH line) but this is not a good way because git tracks that file. Another way is you can add all variables in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Console for your instance environment(the place you set scaling settings)

Comment: I did it on config file but with placeholders and then changed all the values in the AWS EB console

Comment: Maybe it overrides it, I'm not sure. Delete from config file and add it on console.

Comment: apparently it's giving me "name 'hash' is not defined" error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134822/discussion-between-cagatay-barin-and-john-d).